# Different consistency levels for read and write operations

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Is Cassandra allowed to set different consistency level for read and write operation?

Because when I check the documentation from [datastax](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/consistency_r.html), it seems that the consistency level is set the same for both read, write operations.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is true. Cassandra allows us to set Consistency level for both read and write operations and even for per-operation basis.

More info can be found at https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html

Comment: So it means if the "cqlsh CONSISTENCY" return TWO, it means all nodes in the cluster are set to TWO for both read, write operation ?

Comment: @TuanLD `cqlsh consistency` allows you to get/set the default consistency level for both read and write operations of the entire cluster, that is correct. However, you can set a different consistency level on each operation.